# How to retrieve the values from popup to parent view in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a popup which creates input boxes dynamically on popup..I want to display the content of that textboxes on the parent view.The textboxes has an id dynamically as 1,2,3 and so on.If i want to display it in parent view i need to loop it.But how to assign those text in the textboxes to a variable and view it on parent screen.

```
    //popuphtmlfile


    <h3 style="color: #0d7dc1;">Selection Of TextBoxes</h3>
        <br>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="textbox in textboxes">
                    Label For Inputfield:
                        <input type="text" id="in_{{$index}}"/><button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="deletetxtbox()">-</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="expndtxt()">Click to add textboxes</button>
                </li>
          </ul>
        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="savebutton()">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancl()">Cancel</button>

//js file

//for appending textboxes on button click
$scope.expndtxt=function(){


        $scope.textboxes.push({
        });
    };

//deleting if we no need any textbox on the popup
    $scope.deletetxtbox=function(index){

         $scope.textboxes.splice(index, 1);
    };

//if save button is clicked ,when i enter anythnng in the textboxes that must me added to the parent view as a label with a textbox again.


    $scope.savebutton=function(){

        angular.forEach($scope.textboxes,function(t)
                {

                    //The content of text box must be displayed as label name with a new text box
                });

    };
```

Comment: easier if we had some code to look at, just something you have tried or anything

Comment: i have edited .once see it

Answer (score 0):

I am updating my answer to address your latest comments.

Here is a pluker showing how to add a label to a dynamically added textbox. http://plnkr.co/edit/MR9PG0S7PNMNwm7fNX7m?p=preview

The code is pretty straightforward.

HTML in popup

```
<p>Enter label text:</p>
<input type="text" id="generateNew" data-ng-model="box" />
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="expndtxt(box)">Click to add textboxes</button>
```

HTML in parent

```
<li ng-repeat="box in textboxes">
  <label for="box_{{box.id}}">{{box.label}}</label>&nbsp;<input name="box_{{box.id}}" type="textbox" id={{box.id}} data-ng-model="newBox" />
</li>
```

Controller code

```
var counter=0;
$scope.textboxes = [];
$scope.expndtxt = function(tBox){
  counter++;
  $scope.textboxes.push(  { id:counter, label : tBox} );
  $event.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: but i am going to set the value to the parent html when button is clicked

Comment: That is not shown in your code. Please add all relevant functions to your question so we can better help you.

Comment: I have added..if save button is clicked ,the control goes to the savebutton() ,in that this action is to be implemented

Comment: I am able to retrieve the values but could not make that value to label and display it on parent view with a textbox

Comment: You are retrieving the value with jQuery and not in the Angular way. It will be much more difficult displaying the values with the method you are currently using. You would have to apply the jQuery values to the parent window and then run a $digest cycle. Using the ng-model and angular data binding, you can avoid having to do all of that.

Comment: I am retrieving it the same as you said me..its coming in as an object.Can you please say how to take a content of the text boz and name it as label with a text box

Answer (score 0):

You can bind ng-change directive and on each textbox when text is changed you can save it's value to it's corresponding textbox object, where you can itterate later.

```
  //popuphtmlfile


    <h3 style="color: #0d7dc1;">Selection Of TextBoxes</h3>
        <br>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="textbox in textboxes">
                    Label For Inputfield:
                        <input type="text" id="in_{{$index}}" ng-model="textBoxModel[$index]" ng-change="onChange(textBoxModel[$index])"/>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="deletetxtbox()">-</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="expndtxt()">Click to add textboxes</button>
                </li>
          </ul>
        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="savebutton()">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancl()">Cancel</button>

//js file

//for appending textboxes on button click
$scope.expndtxt=function(){


        $scope.textboxes.push({
        });
    };

//deleting if we no need any textbox on the popup
    $scope.deletetxtbox=function(index){

         $scope.textboxes.splice(index, 1);
    };

//if save button is clicked ,when i enter anythnng in the textboxes that must me added to the parent view as a label with a textbox again.


    $scope.savebutton=function(){

        angular.forEach($scope.textboxes,function(t)
                {

                    //The content of text box must be displayed as label name with a new text box
                    //here you can get each textbox text attribute
                    t.text;
                });

    };

//onChange function which will get all text from text-boxes and store it to it's correspondive object

$scope.textBoxOnChange = function(textboxmodel,texboxobject){
    texboxobject.text = textboxmodel;
};
```