# How to append textbox to the parent view from the popup in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a pop up in which i write the text in the text boxes.When i save it the text which i have written must become as label and a text box must be appended beside the label.I have done label,but unable to append text box can anyone help me.

```
      //controller
        $scope.inputs={};
            $scope.textboxes=[];

    //appending textboxes in pop up dynamically

            $scope.expndtxt=function(){


            $scope.textboxes.push({
            });
        };
        //when savebutton clicked

        $scope.savebutton=function(){


                    angular.forEach($scope.textboxes,function(t){

                        $scope.inputs[t]=t.value;

                        ngDialog.closeAll();

                    });


            };
//html
<p data-ng-repeat="input in inputs">{{input.value}}</p>
```

In this it displaying only the content of text boxes.But I am trying to display the content and also a text box beside it.

Comment: Hi! Can you share some code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? From what i understand of your question you want something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101286/how-to-retrieve-the-values-from-popup-to-parent-view-in-angularjs

Comment: I have edited the question once see it

Comment: Angular has services and factories, used for communication between other services and factories or directives and controllers....